# ASP.NET controls disappearing from dynamically built user control

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, user-controls, dynamically-generated

I have a curious problem with an ASP.NET user-control which is dynamically created in VB.NET.  Sorry that this is a long post, but I think it’s better for me to explain carefully what I’m doing and what the problem is.

Essentially, the user-control is an HTML table used to display data from a back-end SQL Server DB.  It uses a stored procedure to return a DataTable, from which it builds html rows and columns with the values stored in the InnerHtml property of the relevant table cell.  This is just a passive display of the data and works perfectly.

However, the user-control also has the facility to insert a new record, triggered by an ASP button.  This causes the following sequence of events;

1. **Post-back**
2. The **user-control_Init** event rebuilds all the existing rows in the table and inserts their values as described above.
3. The **page_Init** event.
4. The **page_Load** event.
5. The **user-control_Load** event.
6. The **button_Click** event then builds a new row with the same structure as the main table.  But this time it inserts into each table cell a relevant ASP.NET control, such as a textbox or checkbox, holding “null” values.  Each control has its ID set explicitly to a unique value.  Finally, an “insert flag” is set to true.

The user then enters the data into these controls and clicks an Insert-Save button.  This causes another post-back, which follows the procedure described above, except that the “insert flag” tells the user-control_Init event (2) to rebuild the insert row.  Then, before the page_Load event (4) the values previously entered by the user are reinstated in the ASP.NET controls from ViewState.  Finally, the Insert-Save_Click event calls a stored procedure to save these data to the DB.

All this work perfectly when there are existing rows in the html table.  But – *and this is the strange behaviour* – it fails when there are no existing rows.  The first post-back completes successfully although, obviously, event 2 skips over the rebuilding of the existing rows because there are none.  However, the insert row is rebuilt correctly and the user can then enter data into the ASP.NET controls.  During the second post-back (Insert-Save), the first three events described above work perfectly.  But, the moment the code hits the page_Load event (4), all the ASP.NET controls disappear.  The html row and cells are still present, including the literal control (index 0) in each cell.   No error is thrown at this stage, but when the Insert-Save_Click event occurs and the data should be read from the ASP.NET controls – they are not available and an "index out-of-bounds" error is thrown, because the ASP.NET controls should each have an index of 1 within their cells.

I’ve spent hours (days!) debugging this and I cannot see what is causing these controls to just evaporate!  Any clever programmers out there got any ideas please?

Comment: You forgot to include the relevant code in the question.

Comment: There is a lot of reading to be done to understand how this works - read all 4 parts of this - https://weblogs.asp.net/infinitiesloop/TRULY-Understanding-Dynamic-Controls-_2800_Part-1_2900_

Comment: Andrew - I deliberately didn't include code in this question because the whole user-control is much more complicated than I have described here.  There are nearly 1000 lines of vb.net!  What I was hoping to do with the detailed description is show that I do understand page cycles (I hope!) and I do know how to step through code to identify exactly what is happening and when.  I'd be happy to send you the code directly if you are interested.

Comment: sh1rts - Thanks for the link but it seems to be redundant.